# Use of AIC in comparing prognostic value of a parameter between two groups

Tags: aic

For my research I want look at the following:

I have a dataset in which there is the variable type of report (NR and SR).
Now I have a prognostic parameter X  on survival and I want to test whether the prognostic value of the parameter is better for SR than NR. So whether it differs between the two groups.

Is it possible to compare the AIC-values of both groups? Or should I use some other kind of statistical method?

Thnx in advance!